# I broke the gagging machine

Tags: bug, chat, moderator-tools, account-suspension

Some users were being annoying in chat, and they had already been kicked enough to trigger moderation flags. In an attempt to stop them being annoying without annoying the other moderators by proxy, I suspended the user.

The "suspend user" dialog box asked for a suspension duration - in hours. Not wanting the suspension to last that long (intending only a 1 minute suspension) I typed in the number 0.01.

Then the site crashed. *

I assume that this is a bug, and so am reporting it as such.

<sub><sup>* well, it displayed [this page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/gag)</sup></sub>